How to use " I have got to hand it to you "
I just want to know how to use this idiom as I came across it yesterday.

I have got to hand it to you, that's a nice question you've posed! (Like that :) ) Also, there's a definition and some helpful usage examples here: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/I+have+to+hand+it+to
